# Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid props.style key `selected` supplied to `Text` with conditional styles

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, expo

After upgrading to expo 48.0.4 i get loads of warnings in the console about my conditional styles.

I have several elements that are like this:

```
            <TouchableOpacity
              key={`day-${dayIndex}`}
              style={[
                styles.calendarCell,
                flexStyles.flexRow,
                flexStyles.justifyCenter,
                flexStyles.alignCenter,
                dayjs(selectedDate).isSame(day, "date") &&
                  styles.calendarCell.selected,
              ]}
            >
```

Which use the stylesheet that is like this:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  calendarCell: {
    width: "12%",
    margin: 2,
    textAlign: "center",
    selected: {
      borderStyle: "solid",
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: Colors.BLUE,
      borderRadius: 4,
    },
  },
});
```

The warning is this:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid props.style key `selected` supplied to `Text`.

//Followed by an object containing the flex-styles, calendarCell-styles and a nested object of selected-styles, like:

{
...(insert other styles here),
    selected: {
      borderStyle: "solid",
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: Colors.BLUE,
      borderRadius: 4,
    },
}

//Followed by a long list of "Valid keys"
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define styles like

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    calendarCell: {
    width: "12%",
    margin: 2,
    textAlign: "center",
  }
  selected: {
    borderStyle: "solid",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: Colors.BLUE,
    borderRadius: 4,
  },
});
```

and using `styles.selected`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't nest style objects inside of each other, this is not how `StyleSheets` work. There are certain keys you can use inside of a `StyleSheet` object, you can check what they are by searching for the types `ViewStyle` `TextStyle` and `ImageStyle`.
What you need to do is instead of having this:

**REMOVE**

```js
  calendarCell: {
    width: "12%",
    margin: 2,
    textAlign: "center",
    selected: {
      borderStyle: "solid",
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: Colors.BLUE,
      borderRadius: 4,
    },
  },
```

Create a selected style object as a separate object:

**ADD**

```js
  calendarCell: {
    width: "12%",
    margin: 2,
    textAlign: "center",
  },
    selected: {
      borderStyle: "solid",
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: Colors.BLUE,
      borderRadius: 4,
    },
```